Solve system of integrated differential equations
I want to solve a system of integrated differential equations but I am encountering a problem with my Mathematica code.
\text{ka}=\text{kb}=1;
\text{wa}=\text{wb}=\frac{w}{2};
\text{Jxy}=0.5;
\text{Jz}=0;
\Gamma =1;
\Omega =\frac{\pi }{4};
\text{initialCondition1}=\text{f1}(t,t)=\text{ka};
\text{initialCondition2}=f_2(t,t)=\text{kb};
\text{initialCondition3}=f_3(t,t)=0;
\text{initialCondition4}=f_4(t,t)=0;
K[t,s]=\frac{1}{2} (\gamma \Gamma ) \exp (-(\gamma +i \Omega ) | t-s| );
F_1=\int_0^t f_1(t,s) K[t,s] , ds;
F_2=\int_0^t f_2(t,s) K[t,s] , ds;
F_3=\int_0^t f_3(t,s) K[t,s] , ds;
F_4=\int_0^t f_4(t,s) K[t,s] , ds;
\text{eq1}=f_1'(t,s)=\text{ka} f_1(t,s) F_1(t,s)+\text{ka} f_4(t,s) F_4(t,s)+\text{kb} f_1(t,s) F_3(t,s)-\text{kb} f_3(t,s) F_1(t,s)+\text{kb} f_4(t,s) F_3(t,s)+\text{kb} f_3(t,s) F_4(t,s)-i \text{Jxy} f_3(t,s)+2 i \text{Jz} f_4(t,s)+2 i \text{wa} f_1(t,s);
\text{eq2}=f_2'(t,s)=\text{ka} f_2(t,s) F_4(t,s)-\text{ka} f_4(t,s) F_2(t,s)+\text{ka} f_4(t,s) F_3(t,s)+\text{ka} f_3(t,s) F_4(t,s)+\text{kb} f_2(t,s) F_2(t,s)+\text{kb} f_3(t,s) F_3(t,s)-i \text{Jxy} f_4(t,s)+2 i \text{Jz} f_3(t,s)+2 i \text{wb} f_2(t,s);
\text{eq3}=f_3'(t,s)=-\text{ka} f_1(t,s) F_2(t,s)+\text{ka} f_1(t,s) F_3(t,s)+\text{ka} f_2(t,s) F_4(t,s)+\text{ka} f_3(t,s) F_4(t,s)+\text{kb} f_3(t,s) F_2(t,s)+\text{kb} f_2(t,s) F_3(t,s)-i \text{Jxy} f_1(t,s)+2 i \text{Jz} f_2(t,s)+2 i \text{wb} f_3(t,s);
\text{eq4}=f_4'(t,s)=\text{ka} f_1(t,s) F_4(t,s)+\text{ka} f_4(t,s) F_1(t,s)+\text{kb} f_1(t,s) F_3(t,s)-\text{kb} f_2(t,s) F_1(t,s)+\text{kb} f_4(t,s) F_3(t,s)+\text{kb} f_2(t,s) F_4(t,s)-i \text{Jxy} f_2(t,s)+2 i \text{Jz} f_1(t,s)+2 i \text{wa} f_4(t,s);
\text{initialCondition1}=f_1(t,t)=\text{ka};
\text{initialCondition2}=f_2(t,t)=\text{kb};
I want to solve a system of integrated differential equations but I am encountering a problem with my Mathematica code. Here my code :
\text{initialCondition3}=f_3(t,t)=0;
\text{initialCondition4}=f_4(t,t)=0;
\text{Null} \left(\text{sol}=\text{NDSolve}\left[{\text{eq1},\text{eq2},\text{eq3},\text{eq4},\text{initialCondition1},\text{initialCondition2},\text{initialCondition3},\text{initialCondition4}},\left{f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4\right},{t,0,20}\right];\right)

Radia, here is some help how to format your post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting Can you follow these recommendations?

And here is another useful post about the formatting: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor
